# Table is emptying after interaction with Datatable features

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatable

I was trying to populate my table using this code and it worked fine.

The problem is, I try to sort or search the table using the features of datatable, my table is being emptied.

```js
$('#ipcrTable').DataTable({
  responsive: true
});

function get_ipcr() {
  var userID = <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ipcr.php",

    dataType: "json",
    success: function(results) {
      $.each(results, function(i, val) {
        $('#ipcrTable tr:last').after('<tr> <td>' + val.dateCreated + '</td><td>' + val.details + '</td></tr>');
      });
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ipcrTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time Created</th>
      <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="itBody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to populate the table by hard coding the data into the table and the DataTable works fine. I'm not sure why but after using the search and other features of the DataTable, it erases the data that was printed by my get_ipcr() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables doesn't know about the updated DOM content, so you should use the DataTables api methods to update the table using [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) followed by a [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) to redraw the table. Here's a snippet demonstrating:

```js
var table = $('#ipcrTable').DataTable({
  responsive: true
});

function get_ipcr() {
  var results = [
    {"dateCreated" : "2018-08-29", "details" : "today!"},
    {"dateCreated" : "2018-07-04", "details" : "july 4th"},
    {"dateCreated" : "2019-03-20", "details" : "spring equinox"}
  ];
  $.each(results, function(i, val) {
    table.row.add([val.dateCreated,val.details]);
  });
  table.draw();
}

get_ipcr()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="ipcrTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time Created</th>
      <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="itBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's what it might look like in your own code:

```
var table = $('#ipcrTable').DataTable({
    responsive: true
});

function get_ipcr() {
    var userID = <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ipcr.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(results) {
            $.each(results, function(i, val) {
                table.row.add([val.dateCreated,val.details]);
            });
            table.draw(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!